# Can models like chatGPT learn functions with infinite domain or range

Tags: neural-networks, deep-neural-networks, chatgpt

Lets assume two types of prompt:
A fixed prompt for which reasonable responses can be infinite. For example:

```
> output a random number
> output a palindrome
```

A prompt that can slightly varied to get different output each time which reasonable mapping. Quotes mark what will be varied.

```
> what is the double of "2"
> echo "xyz"
```

Now that the network is trained on finite data and has finite parameters, does it inherently   prevent it from perfectly answering these questions each time.

If yes, can a tiny network be handcrafted to model an infinite domain function and its only the "learning from data" part that prevents it from learning such functions.

Comment: GPT models have a fixed amount of context - previous outputs and prompts they can look back on. Something like 2048 tokens. After the prompt falls out of the window the next generation won't see the prompt any more, however it will still see 2048 tokens worth of random numbers and it has a good chance of generating more random numbers after that. It probably can't generate any palindrome longer than the context size. There can be other model designs without this limitation, but GPT models do have it.

Comment: The transformer model (prior to GPT) has completely separate windows for prompt and output, so it can always see the prompt even if the output gets really long. GPT threw away half the model as it turned out you could put both in the same window.

Comment: so basically it depends on the network architecture

Comment: ChatGPT cannot even count the words in sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the design of the model, of course.

The overall design of a GPT model is like this: the last certain number of tokens (e.g. 2048) are passed into a neural network which outputs probabilities for the next token. Then a next token is chosen according to the probabilities. This repeats until something. So it can't see more than a certain number of tokens back - and that's the fault of how it's designed. If you ask it to generate a longer palindrome, it will eventually forget the beginning of the palindrome and also forget the instruction to generate a palindrome. However, if you ask it to generate random numbers, as long as the inputs are random numbers it will probably keep generating more random numbers.

Other kinds of models exist, like RNNs, which process one token at a time and remember some data between tokens. Theoretically, an RNN could keep passing information down the chain indefinitely. In practice, they do not. Also, nobody has made one work as well as GPT.

Transformer models, the precursor to GPT, worked like GPT but they did have separate prompt and output strings. The input is the last certain number of output tokens, plus all the input tokens. This kind of model would not forget the instruction to generate a palindrome, but it would forget the beginning of the palindrome after a while.

Comment: An encoder-decoder transformer isn't a precursor to GPT; it is for machine translation, whilst GPT, the transformer decoder, is for causal language modelling. Also, there is nothing in the design of transformers or GPT that fixes the input size (which is how recent GPT models are able to have very long contexts); they are as recurrent as an RNN, except with better long-range dependencies since there is no bottleneck that moves through the context.

Comment: @Mew GPT was created based on half of a transformer. GPT uses a position embedding with a fixed number of positions.